# Postgres text search vector(tsv)- saving complete phrases with space as search token in text search vector

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

Can we save the complete name with spaces as one of the tsvs. For example, if I have 'Test 6' as the name, can I save 'test', **'test 6'** as text search vectors.

I am currently running into issues with search on postgres where the search is done on text search vectors(tsv).

Use Case:
I have a column 'groupName' which is converted into text search vectors(tsv) and saved, and then all my search requests goes against those tsv's.
To overcome a certain use case we are stripping off the last digit from the group name. For example if the group name is 'Test 6', we strip off 6 and save only 'test' in tsv. The 'groupName' column as such will still have the complete name with the digit.
Now the issue it creates it if we do a search on exact match ('Test 6' in this case), it will not be returned in the result, but I do search only for 'Test', the result will have 'Test 6' also.

Can we save the complete name with spaces as one of the tsvs.

Comment: You will have to create a thesaurus dictionary and use that in your text search configuration.

Comment: You can save almost whatever you want as the tsvector, as long as you format it correctly.    But if your generation of the tsvector is not consistent with your generation of the tsquery, you will not get the results you want.  We normally use to_tsvector and the *to_tsquery functions, but you can do it all by hand if you want.

Comment: thanks @jjanes. In my case, we are using to_tsquery. So that seems to be working fine. Since we are stripping out the last digit where present  from the groupNames before running it through to_tsvector  its causing an issue with the search. So, I am trying to figure out how do I save the complete name as is as one of the tsvectors(for ex. "Test 6" should generate vectots as ['test', '6', 'test 6'])

Comment: Could you show the specific to_tsquery call you are using for the search?

Comment: Nevermind @jjanes. Managed to get the stripped last digit back to tsv with lower weight. Thanks for your help!!